# Oauth2 authentication in Angular 6 and spring boot are on different host

Tags: angular, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I've frontend application is written on Angular 6 and backend app(REST) is written Spring Boot.

I need authorization through social network VK.

What have I already done?
Backend server interceprs all request, checks authenthication, if user didn't authenthication, server send url VK API for authenthication through VK, client(frontend) sent request to API VK with redirect uri of backend service. VK redirect to backend service with code, and backend send new request to VK for receiving token, after receiving of token Backend does redirect to client.

I think, it's wrong, because it's not common way, if I want to develop mobile software, how I will do redirect at depend on my client?

Please, tell me. What architecture should be for my application, if frontend and backend are separate.